# simulate observations and calculate sample autocorrelation

Tags: r, simulation

Simulating rk (r stands for autocorrelation) for {et} where each et is iid N(0,1).
R code: simulate 100 observations of {et} and calculate r1.
Here is my code so far:

```
x=rnorm(100,0,1)
x
y=ts(x)
trial_r1=acf(y)[1]
trial_r1
```

Is my code right？ How to get r1 after running acf()

Comment: `acf(y)$acf` provides direct access to the array of autocorrelation values, though off-by-one. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

*(I'll post as an answer, both to close the question, plus to help with searching for answers to similarly-structured questions.)*

When looking for what you believe is but one part of a structured return, it's useful to look at the return value in detail. One common way to do this is with `str`:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
ret <- acf(ts(x))
str(ret)
## List of 6
##  $ acf   : num [1:21, 1, 1] 1 0.05592 -0.00452 0.03542 0.00278 ...
##  $ type  : chr "correlation"
##  $ n.used: int 100
##  $ lag   : num [1:21, 1, 1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
##  $ series: chr "ts(x)"
##  $ snames: NULL
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr "acf"
```

In this instance, you'll see two clusters of numbers in `$acf` and `$lag`. The latter "clearly" is just an array of incrementing integers so is not that interesting in this endeavor, but the former looks more interesting. By seeing that the results is ultimately just a `list`, you can use dollar-sign subsetting (or `[[`, over to you) to extract what you need:

```
ret$acf
## , , 1
##                [,1]
##  [1,]  1.000000e+00
##  [2,]  5.592310e-02
##  [3,] -4.524017e-03
##  [4,]  3.541639e-02
##  [5,]  2.784590e-03
##  ...snip...
```

In the case of your question, you should notice that the first element of this 3-dimensional array is the perfectly-autocorrelated `1`, but your first real autocorrelation of concern is the second element, or `0.0559`. So your first value is attainable with `ret$acf[2,,]` (or more formally `ret$acf[2,1,1]`).

Comment: Is it good enough to "accept"? It's good form to close questions that have been answered.